# Populate ITemplate by code

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to fill an `ITemplate` by code?
Let's suppose I have an `UpdatePanel`:

```
UpdatePanel upnl = new UpdatePanel();
// What should be done next?
//upnl.ContentTemplate = ...
```

and the result of it would be equivalent of:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upnl">
    <ContentTemplate>
    test
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do if I understood your question correctly:

```
public class YourTemplate : ITemplate 
{
    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        container.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("test"));
    }
}

...
upnl.ContentTemplate = new YourTemplate();
```

Comment: I was trying the same thing, but I didn't transmitted the content right, so I was seeing empty.

Comment: @misha what did you have to fix to stop seeing an empty result?

Comment: I figured out my problem.  My new Web Control I was adding needed to be local to the InstantiateIn method rather than a private variable on the template class.

Answer (score 1):

All the Template enabled Controls in ASP.net must implement [System.Web.UI.ITemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itemplate.aspx) interface to create Template at run time.

> But You need not to create custom Template class in case of update
>   panel. Check [UpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.contenttemplatecontainer.aspx) -

The ContentTemplateContainer property enables you to programmatically add child controls to the UpdatePanel control without having to define a custom template that inherits from the `ITemplate` interface. If you are adding content to the UpdatePanel control declaratively or through a designer, you should add content to the ContentTemplate property by using a `<ContentTemplate> element`.

Check this code snippet- For more details check the `ContentTemplateContainer` link above.

```
UpdatePanel up1 = new UpdatePanel();
up1.ID = "UpdatePanel1";
Button button1 = new Button();
button1.ID = "Button1";
button1.Text = "Submit";
button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
up1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(button1);
Page.Form.Controls.Add(up1);
```